# How to read folder path dynamically?

Tags: java

Let's say I have path like

> "jboss/server/Default/deploy/Product_071016.ear/Product_071016.war/web-inf/classes/"

I want to read this path using java and create a new file inside classes folder. Hard-Coding is not an option and it needs to be adaptable.

In this path `Product_071016.ear` and `Product_071016.war` names changes(i.e. date,month,year is appended after "_").
How can I do this?

Comment: Question has wrong tittle (nothing about web container environment) and as a result answers seems far from asker idea. Maybe I wrong, that is possible too. My English isn't perfect, cant help more.

Comment: @Naveen Dhalaria: Did you see my answer? When *JacekCz* mentioned about the possibility of a wrong title I noticed may be the requirement is not elaborated well. Does my answer fit your requirements? Also I edited the path as you edited from **firstgen** to **Product**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depend on your requirements, you can have some options, such as:

1. Have a config file, for example: **paths.properties**

   which contains every dynamically changing path as a `key/value` pair in each line. You can find out about the format of `.properties` files [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwikqdXk9-jNAhXDVxQKHaMbCAcQFgghMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fcd%2FE23095_01%2FPlatform.93%2FATGProgGuide%2Fhtml%2Fs0204propertiesfileformat01.html&usg=AFQjCNG9O2BQn3D3kaOKq1oR6d6Y97b4Zw). The key is a  *CONSTANT* name. Every time the path changes, somebody should change the value assign to this constant key in the **paths.properties**. Since you can load this config file using a `Properties` object in `java`, you can have the changed path by giving it's *CONSTANT* key to the `Properties` object. `Properties` is somehow a customized `Map` for dealing with `.properties` files.

   The contents of your **paths.properties** can be like this:

   ```
    PATH_TO_CLASSES_FOLDER=jboss/server/Default/deploy/Product_071016.ear/Product_071016.war/web-inf/classes/
   ```

   So after you loaded the `key/values` from `.properties` file using `Properties` object, by giving the key `PATH_TO_CLASSES_FOLDER` you get the desired path which is stored in the file.
2. You can set an `System Variable` in every Operating System, and then you can read it's value in java using the following line of code:

   ```
   String pathToClassesFolder = System.getenv("PATH_TO_CLASSES");
   ```

Using either ways, you didn't hard-code any dynamic path in your code and the requirement is achieved. Even if you don't want to hard-code the path of the config file, you can combine both ways:

1. Define the path of config file as a `System Variable`
2. Read the path to config file, then load it by `Properties` object and use the `PATH_TO_CLASSES_FOLDER` key to get the `classes` folder path.

Good Luck.